# How to group max values from column for each month SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote a query that shows me months, customerID and total money that each customer spent. Now I want to show month and customer that spent the most money. Can you help me with this, I do not know how to get `max(money)` from all customers by month. Also `Total_Money` is get by multiplying two other columns `quantity*unitprice` .

I get this with my code:

```
------------------------------------
|  month | customer id |Total money|
------------------------------------
| April  |    12347    | value 1   |
------------------------------------
| April  |   12347     | value 2   |
------------------------------------
| April  |   12347     | value 3   |
------------------------------------
```

And I want to get this (id of a customer that spent the most money for each month ):

```
----------------------------------------
|  month |  customer id  | Total money  |
----------------------------------------
| April  | id of customer|value of money|
----------------------------------------
| May    | id of customer|value of money|
----------------------------------------
| June   | id of customer|value of money|
----------------------------------------
```

This is to code that I have:

```
SELECT to_char(invoicedate, 'Month') as Month_Name, customerid,
       SUM((quantity*unitprice)::numeric(15, 2)) as Total_Money
FROM public."My_OnlineRetail"
GROUP BY Month_Name, customerid
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1):

Postgres supports `distinct on`, so you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (to_char(invoicedate, 'Month')) 
       to_char(invoicedate, 'Month') as Month_Name, customerid,
       SUM((quantity*unitprice)::numeric(15, 2) ) as Total_Money
FROM public."My_OnlineRetail"
GROUP BY Month_Name, customerid
ORDER BY Month_Name, Total_money DESC;
```

I should note that `to_char(invoicedate, 'Month')` is suspicious.  It does not take the year into account.  I much prefer `date_trunc()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('month', invoicedate)) 
       date_trunc('month', invoicedate) as Month_Name, customerid,
       SUM( (quantity*unitprice)::numeric(15, 2) )  as Total_Money
FROM public."My_OnlineRetail"
GROUP BY Month_Name, customerid
ORDER BY Month_Name, Total_money DESC;
```

Comment: This is great, but I do not understand this part:` DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('month', invoicedate)) 
       date_trunc('month', invoicedate) as Month_Name`

Whats `DISTINCT ON` and why do you have two times  `date_trunc('month', invoicedate)`

Comment: @Aleksandar . . . https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT.

Comment: Ok, thanks, 
Is there any way to do this with `MAX(Total_money )` ?

Comment: You would start by using `MAX()` instead of `SUM()`.

Comment: I have tried with `MAX() `but it gives me different results

Comment: @Aleksandar . . . Ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear description of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CTE` from your query and `group` it by `Month_Name` to get the maximum money spent per month. Finally join this result to the `CTE` again and get the customer's id also:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    to_char(invoicedate, 'Month') as Month_Name, 
    customerid,
    SUM((quantity*unitprice)::numeric(15, 2)) as Total_Money
  FROM public."My_OnlineRetail"
  GROUP BY Month_Name, customerid
)

SELECT c.Month_Name, c.customerid, g.Max_Month_Money
FROM cte c INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Month_Name, MAX(Total_Money) Max_Month_Money 
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY Month_Name
) g
ON g.Month_Name = c.Month_Name AND g.Max_Month_Money = c.Total_Money
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `with` statement to set up a temporary table which is easier to select your final result from:

```
with
month_cust as (
    select
      to_char(invoicedate,'YYYY-MM') yyyymm,
      customerid,
      sum(quantity*unitprice) total_money
    from my_online_retail
    group by 
      to_char(invoicedate,'YYYY-MM'),
      customerid
)
select yyyymm, customerid, total_money
from month_cust m
where not exists (  -- where not exists a better customer that month:
         select 1 from month_cust
         where yyyymm=m.yyyymm and total_money>m.total_money
)
order by 1,2;
```

I also changed your `to_char(invoicedate,'Month')` into `to_char(invoicedate,'YYYY-MM')` to not add Aprils *of all years* together. I'm guessing you want 2018's April separate from 2019's April.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by Total money as descending and fetch the first row :

```
WITH "My_OnlineRetail_"( invoicedate, customerid, quantity, unitprice ) AS
(
 SELECT date'2018-04-10',12347, 50, 15 union all
 SELECT date'2018-05-13',12348, 60, 20 union all
 SELECT date'2018-06-23',12349, 55, 12  
), "My_OnlineRetail" AS
(
SELECT to_char(invoicedate, 'Month') as Month_Name, customerid,
       SUM((quantity*unitprice)::numeric(15, 2)) as Total_Money
  FROM "My_OnlineRetail_"
 GROUP BY Month_Name, customerid
)
SELECT *
  FROM "My_OnlineRetail"
 ORDER BY Total_Money desc 
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;

month_name  customerid  total_money
May         12348       1200
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/LOCVO33927)</kbd>